# Time from month number to a month name?

Tags: java

I just need to change **month number** to a **month name**...

I tried to put three M's instead of two, and it shows error.
I kinda know the problem but  don't know how to fix it.

```
DateTimeFormatter formater = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy");

Person[] people = new Person[parts.length / 4];
int br = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 4) {
    LocalDate datum = LocalDate.parse(parts[i + 2], formater);
    people[br++] = new Person(parts[i], parts[i + 1],datum, parts[i + 3]);
}
```

Instead of "1988-05-05",
this "1988-May-05" ...

Comment: What is your input? String or Date? and in what format? And what is your expected output?

Comment: Parsing and formating are two different things

Comment: Can you show us to create a new Person (how does the c'tor looks like)?

Comment: Do you need the entire name of the month or would the first three letters be sufficient? In the latter case, just use the `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy")` or any similar one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following can be used for formatting the way you want:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").format(LocalDate.now()) //2019-02-04
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd").format(LocalDate.now()) //2019-Feb-04
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMMM-dd").format(LocalDate.now()) //2019-February-04
```

Comment: It was verry helpfull!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 int month=5;
 String name = java.time.Month.values()[month-1].name();
```

It has also a getDisplayName method:

```
 String name = java.time.Month.values()[month-1].getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault());
```

or(from commment)

```
  String name =java.time.Month.of(month).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault());`
```

(or something alike)

Comment: There is also `java.time.Month.of(int)` which directly takes the month as input, no need for accessing the `values()` array directly

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've already parsed your date. To convert a LocalDate to the kind of string you'd like, you can use the following formatter:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 1);

DateTimeFormatter out = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, TextStyle.SHORT)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
    .toFormatter(Locale.UK); // or your locale

System.out.println(
    out.format(date)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

First you parse a `String` representation of a `Date` like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formater = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy");
LocalDate datum = LocalDate.parse("04022019", formater);
```

Now if the parsing succeeded and you have a valid `LocalDate` object, 
you can format it:

```
String date = datum.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd"));
System.out.println(date);
```

will print

```
2019-Feb-04
```

Comment: I have tryed that method, but, it's printing me an error message.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '05051988' could not be parsed at index 2. This is what it shows.

Comment: The format you need to parse `'05051988'` is `"ddMMyyyy"` just like the code in my answer. If you do it like this then there can be no error. If you get an error then you are doing something else, so post your code.

Answer (score 1):

The LocalDate class also provides several getter methods to extract these values as shown below:

```
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.of(2019, 02, 04);
(OR)
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now(); // 2019-02-04 

DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = currentDate.getDayOfWeek(); // TUESDAY 
int dom = currentDate.getDayOfMonth(); // 04 
int doy = currentDate.getDayOfYear(); //  35
Month month = currentDate.getMonth(); // FEBRUARY
int year = currentDate.getYear(); // 2019
```